# UWP app how to show status bar in fullscreen?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal

Update 1: Updated with pictures and more details:

Update 2: Changed the tittle to reflect better on the problem since the navigation bar cant be manually controlled like the status bar

Okay so I want to overlay the status bar on an app and hide the nav bar.
I achieved this by using: (this is all inside app.xaml.cs)

```
    public override async Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {

        //this allows nav bar and status bar to overlay the app
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseCoreWindow);

        //this hides nav bar and status bar
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
    {
```

So if i comment out

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

the app is still something like full screen but now the nav bar just overlays the app. And not with the fullscreen behavior(i noticed) its just the regular nav bar so fullscreen is needed. But when on fullscreen the following code will never display the status bar no matter where in the app i call it.

```
var statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
await statusBar.ShowAsync();
```

pictures:

With the Fullscreen line: [App](http://prnt.sc/c8v5sj) / [Code](http://prntscr.com/c8v6eu)

Without the Fullscreen line:[App](http://prntscr.com/c8v70s) / [Code](http://prntscr.com/c8v791)

So i need a way to allow the status bar to be displayed on fullscreen.

This app is an open source project "Pokemon Go Client for WM" on git. I want to achieve for it what i try above not only for this app but for my education too. You can find the project here if you are intrested [Pokemon Go-UWP for WM](https://github.com/ST-Apps/PoGo-UWP)

Comment: Draw your own status bar.

Comment: Can you add some pics what did you get and what did you want?

Comment: And some xaml might help to. Sounds like an layouting issue

Comment: okay sorry for being late will now add a picture!! and more details

Comment: [This](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/021dde88-04bd-4fd6-b163-288d040b0d9d/uwpxaml-chow-to-make-statusbar-overlay-the-app?forum=wpdevelop) may help you out, depending on your device as it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows Mobile, a full-screen app has no Status Bar and no Navigation Bar. And there is no way to show Status Bar while it is in full-screen mode. As @Raymond's suggest, you can draw your own status bar like adding battery power and date time info in the upper right corner of your app. But this may be not easy to implement.

As you've seen, without full-screen mode,

> the app is still something like full screen but now the nav bar just overlays the app.

So I think you can also hide the navigation bar to achieve what you want. Alought, we can not hide navigation bar programmatically, but users can swipe up from the bottom of the screen to hide/show it. You can add some tips in your app to prompt users to hide the navigation bar.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S60v.png)

Or you can set desired bounds mode to **UseVisible** like following to lay out the window's content within the visible region.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetDesiredBoundsMode(ApplicationViewBoundsMode.UseVisible);
```

In this mode, application won't take the region occluded the status bar or navigation bar.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuuNd.png)

Comment: So there is no way to at least force the navigation bar to hide ??

Comment: @PanosPanosAthanasiou There is no API can hide the navigation bar by now. But you are welcome to ask for this feature with using **Feedback Hub** or [**UserVoice**](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform).

Comment: Hey no its not :/ and i dont think there will be other way than making a custom one in the future. Will use corewindow till find a way to display the bar or when MS provides us of a way!! or at least controls to nav bar. Thnx for answering tho you gave me other ideas at least for personal use!!